# Angular 2 & Vanilla JS : Wait for images to load before making http calls

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am using a service to upload images on a server. Here it is :

```
addPictures(files: File[], folder: string): Observable<Parse.Object[]> {
  let hasError = false;
  for (let file of files) {
    let [type, ext] = file.type.split('/');
    if (type.toLowerCase() !== 'image' || !environment.imgExts.includes(ext.toLowerCase())) { hasError = true; }
  }
  if (hasError) { return Observable.throw('Invalid extension detected'); }

  let observables: Observable<Parse.Object>[] = [];

  for (let file of files) {
    // Get its size
    let img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => {
      // Create the Parse document
      let parseImg = { url: '', type: file.type, width: img.width, height: img.height };
      // Upload it on Amazon and add it to DB
      observables.push(this.addPicture(parseImg, file, folder));
      console.log('pushing to array');
    }
    img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
  }
  console.log('forkjoin');
  return Observable.forkJoin(observables);
}
```

All the functions works great. The problem I'm facing is that when I use `img.onload`, the `forkJoin` doesn't wait for it before firing. What I would like is **wait for all the images to load, then trigger thr forkJoin to send them all**.

I already have tried with a condition (when last item is pushed to array, trigger the forkJoin), with a subject, but the problem is that my component returns an error along the lines of `Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined`.

**EDIT** here is my code for thr fromEvent :

```
addPictures(files: File[], folder: string): Observable<Parse.Object[]> {
  let hasError = false;
  for (let file of files) {
    let [type, ext] = file.type.split('/');
    if (type.toLowerCase() !== 'image' || !environment.imgExts.includes(ext.toLowerCase())) { hasError = true; }
  }
  if (hasError) { return Observable.throw('Invalid extension detected'); }

  let observables: Observable<Parse.Object>[] = [];

  for (let file of files) {
    // Get its size
    let img = this.fromImgEvent(file, window.URL.createObjectURL(file), folder);
    observables.push(img);
  }
  console.log('forkjoin');
  return Observable.forkJoin(observables);
}

fromImgEvent(file: File, url: string, folder: string) {
  return Observable.create(observer => {
    let img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => {
      // Create the Parse document
      let parseImg = { url: '', type: file.type, width: img.width, height: img.height };
      // Upload it on Amazon and add it to DB
      observer.next(this.addPicture(parseImg, file, folder));
      observer.complete();
    }
    img.src = url;
  });
}
```

Comment: Did you try the `Observable.fromEvent` operator, to listen to the onload event as an observable.

Comment: No, I have no knowledge of that, could you make a quick example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use for example `Observable.fromEvent` or create an Observable by yourself for a loading image like so:

```js
addPictures(files: File[], folder: string): Observable<Parse.Object[]> {
  let hasError = false;
  let data$ = files.map(file => {
    let [type, ext] = file.type.split('/');
    if (type.toLowerCase() !== 'image' || !environment.imgExts.includes(ext.toLowerCase())) { 
      hasError = true;
    }
    return Observable.create(observer => {
        let image = new Image();
        image.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
        image.onload = (e) => {
            let parsedImage = { url: '', type: file.type, width: image.width, height: image.height };
            observer.next({ parsedImage, file });
            observer.complete();
        };
    });
  };
  if (hasError) { 
    return Observable.throw('Invalid extension detected');
  }
  return Observable
    .forkJoin(data$)
    .toArray()
    .switchMap(([parsedData]) => {
        return Observable.forkJoin(
            parsedData.map(data => {
                return this.addPicture(data.parsedImage, data.file, folder)
            })
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: Just tested it, and the forkjoin is still getting trigerred before the array of observable has values ...

Comment: Can u add a plunkr with a test case? Or add your code with this extension to the question?

Comment: Wait I forgot to actually make the http calls ahah. I'm adding it and testing, and I'll let you know !

Comment: I have updated my question, I can't make a simple plunkr out of that, sorry

Comment: I've updated my answer and added the `toArray` operator after the `forkJoin`, this should wait for all images to complete.

Comment: No difference, all it did was changing the return type by adding a depth to the returned array ...

Comment: You didn't get my point : I don't want to load the images, what I want is to **send the images to my DB**. What I do is that I hook the load event to get the size of the image, and once it's done, I send those informations to my DB. Loading the image isn't a problem, my problem is that I want **to send all the image data to my back-end, only once all images are loaded** !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150090/discussion-between-cyrix-and-trichetriche).